# MYSQL GET ALL PATHS FROM TABLE

Tags: mysql, search, relationship

I have been trying for some time to find the right query to meet the need which is to find all paths from one user to all other users, namely :

I have a table named `links` :

```sql
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LINKS; 
    
    CREATE TABLE LINKS (person CHAR(3), parent CHAR(3), link_type int);
    
    INSERT INTO LINKS VALUES 
    ('002','001',0),
    ('003','001',1),
    ('004','001',1),
    ('004','002',2),
    ('005','002',3),
    ('006','005',2),
    ('005','003',2),
    ('007','002',0),
    ('001', NULL,0); <== ADDED WHEN SEARCHING FOR PATH FROM '001'
```

The MySql query is :

```sql
    WITH RECURSIVE ascendants AS 
    (
      SELECT person, CAST(person AS CHAR(500)
    )     AS path FROM LINKS WHERE person='001' 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT t.person, CONCAT(d.path, '=>', t.person) 
            FROM ascendants d, LINKS t 
            WHERE t.parent=d.person) 
    SELECT DISTINCT(PATH), floor((LENGTH(REPLACE(PATH,',','')) / 3) -1) as level 
    FROM ascendants 
    WHERE LENGTH(PATH) > 3 ORDER BY path;
```

1- WHEN I SEARCH FOR ALL PATHS FROM USER : '001' THE RESULTS OF MySql request must be :

```
'001'=>'002'
'001'=>'002'=>'004'
'001'=>'002'=>'005'
'001'=>'002'=>'005'=>'006'
'001'=>'002'=>'007'
'001'=>'003'
'001'=>'003'=>'005'
'001'=>'003'=>'005'=>'006'
'001'=>'004'
```

WITH THIS QUERY THE RESULTS ARE OK.

2- WHEN I SEARCH FOR ALL PATHS FROM USER : '005' THE RESULTS OF MySql query must be : (Note that the last insert statement must be replaced by : ('005', NULL,0);
AND THE RESULTS ARE KO.
Found only paths :

'005'=>'006'

and expected to find :

```
'005'=>'003'
'005'=>'003'=>'001'
'005'=>'003'=>'001'=>'002'
'005'=>'003'=>'001'=>'003'
'005'=>'003'=>'001'=>'004'
'005'=>'003'=>'001'=>'002'=>'004'
'005'=>'003'=>'001'=>'002'=>'005'
'005'=>'003'=>'001'=>'002'=>'005'=>'006'
'005'=>'003'=>'001'=>'002'=>'007'
'005'=>'002'
'005'=>'006'
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Ok, question edited. thanks for your attention.

Comment: more usefulness of a procedure for this treatment.
I changed my search method and modified my MySql tables.

Comment: Reason: Nobody could help me on stackOverflow

Comment: I have not used Recursive, so I can't help.  However, the reason no one has helped is that you haven't made it easy for them.  The best way is to put all this in a **dbfiddle** and post its link here.  Then all they have to do is to tweak your query, instead of creating tables and entering data.....